# Does CRI-O support live upgrade without restarting containers?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have an on-prem kubeadm created Kubernetes cluster running on Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed cri-o as container runtime. Since, it is claimed by CRI-O that it supports zero downtime during live upgrades, as it doesn't restart the containers when the CRI-O service is restarted.

In my cluster, when I restart cri-o service (systemctl restart crio), all the containers are restarted. Is there any specific configuration that I am missing that will avoid the restart of the container when the cri-o daemon is restarted?

Comment: You are correct, CRI-O containers should not restart with service. Maybe check your service script, any chance it would be the one shutting down your containers? Can you share CRI-O version, configuration, maybe the steps you've followed setting it up? I doubt it would help, but have you tried with a recent OS/kernel -- 18.04 is getting old